# Kohana ORM finds only a first record?

Tags: php, orm, kohana

I am using ORM in Kohana and I want to get some record with id = 2 , but when I used:

```
$user = ORM::factory('user');
$user->find(2);
echo $user->name;
```

the result of it is always show me a value of a first record in table `users`, whats wrong with it?

Comment: What happens with a non-existent id, like `999999999` or `-1` or `0`?

Comment: Kohana is 3.2.0 other ids is the same value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per code, `find()` does not expect arguments:

> https://github.com/kohana/orm/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/orm.php#L894

and per documentation:

> http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM#find

and `find()` is only to load first record from database. To avoid that, just use:

```php
$user = ORM::factory('user');
$user = $user->where('id', '=', 2)->find();
echo $user->name;
```

Please test it, as I haven't been using Kohana for a long time now.

Comment: excellent, thank you! And not by theme a lit bit, but I'm intersted in what you using now if it's not a secret?

Comment: and also I would like to know how to find a record by a few rows at once?

Comment: @VictorCzechov: There is also another way, using `factory` call, described her: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM#factory. Answering your other question: no, it is not a secret, but I am using various technologies. For a framework I prefer Django, however in PHP world Symfony 2 looks promising. (anyone not interested: sorry for spam)

Comment: @VictorCzechov: To obtain more rows, you can perform a query the same way (using `where()`, `and_where()`, `or_where()`, `where_open()`, `where_close()` and various methods of query builder) and end it with `find_all()`. I believe you will get an iterator and you would be able to iterate through the result of `find_all()`.

Comment: Thanks, I am only on start with ORM. I know query builder methods. Just I thought that ORM can do where and and_where too.

Comment: @VictorCzechov: Yes, it should be able to perform pretty much the same Query Builder does, so methods other than `where()` and `and_where()` should work also (even joining, offsets etc.). For a complete list of methods, just visit this: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM

Answer (score 4):

As @Tadeck says, `find()` doesn't expect arguments.

Try using the id in the `ORM::factory` call:

```
$user = ORM::factory('user', 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting the primary key for the ORM object?

protected $_primary_key

http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/ORM#find indicates that find attempts to locate the item based upon the primary key.

Comment: It appears it may be a difference in Kohana versions.

Comment: Your solution requires overriding the model (because `$_primary_key` is `protected`), so it seems to be an overkill. @KimE: Yes, the 3.2 from the question is described here: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM#find

Comment: Right, this looks like it would come from the DB